# How to call method from another object in object?

Tags: reactjs

It is pretty easy when I use it like that

```
const Object = {
property: propertyFromAnotherObject.method
}
```

but I want to have this method with my own one

```
myOwnMethod: () => {
            localStorage.setItem('Storage', null);
}
```

my attemps to connect end up with fail.

```
     MyOwnProperty: () => {
            localStorage.setItem('Storage', null);
propertyFromAnotherObject.method         },
```

Answer (score 0):

to call an object,simply append the method to an  object reference with an interventing '. ' (period), and provide any arguments to the method within enclosing parentheses. If the method does not require any arguments, just use empty parentheses.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).